# WhatsApp Web is asking to update Chrome while using Chromium

Tags: chromium, whatsapp

I am using Chromium Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

This morning my WhatsApp Web tab asked me to update Chrome with the following message:

> WhatsApp works with Google Chrome 36+
>   To use WhatsApp, update Chrome
>   or use Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Microsoft Edge or Opera.

What should I do to get WhatsApp Web running again?

Comment: WhatApp webdevs have to learn about feature detection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(web_development)

Comment: This is broken again, and the UA trick dosent resolve it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the [User agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) Chromium for Linux is using right now. It is using *Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36* which WhatsApp web is recognizing as an older User Agent which Chrome used before version 36. I have also observed that the problem is with Chromium for Linux only since on the other hand WhatsApp web seems to work perfectly under Chromium version 71.0.3578.80 on Windows which uses User agent as *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3641.0 Safari/537.36*.

So, to run WhatsApp web again you need to change the User Agent. Do remember to clear all cookies and temporary data to get these working since temporary data might create problems. There are two ways to change user agent:

#### 1. Using Chromium Settings:

- Open New Tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open Developer Tools
- Click on Hamburger menu (vertical dots) and choose *More tools - Network conditions*

  [image: Enable Network Conditions]
- Go to the *Network conditions* tab (should appear in bottom right), disable the option *Select automatically* and choose *Chrome - Windows* from drop-down menu.

  [image: Select other UA]
- **Note**: You need to perform all things again once WhatsApp web is opened in new tab or Chromium is relaunched since *Settings* are applied only for that Tab and aren't remembered for a particular site.

#### 2. Using an extension:

- Download and install [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)
- This extension doesn't have any User agents for Chrome. So, you need to add a new custom User Agent or use in-built user agents, for example, Internet Explorer/Safari/Firefox.
- If you want to stick to "Chromium on Ubuntu" as User Agent:

  - Right Click (or two finger tap) on the extension in top bar and click on *Options*
  - A list will open which would look like

  [image: Options Page]

  - Click on **New User-agent name**. Give any name you like and as User-agent enter this **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.75 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36**. Give group name as **Chrome**, in **Append?**, choose **Replace** and in **Flag** field enter **New**. Click on **Add**.
- Now, click on extension in top bar and change the UA to this newly created custom UA or some other UA (if not created).

  [image: Setting UA]
- In this case UA is applied universally to all tabs.

Once you're done with one of the above ways, open [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com) to login.

Comment: Change user agent string but avoid changing OS, keep linux based. It works and it avoids you problems with web apps that uses os detection

Comment: @DiegoBetto Chromium doesn't have any UA as *Chrome - Ubuntu/Linux* in-built. Also, I've used UA of Chromium for Windows for second approach. Since in this solution we are focused on a particular site so IMO it doesn't matter if we change OS if we know about the site.

Comment: this works for me only if i delete cookies for web.whatsapp.com first

Comment: I tried many solutios, and the first one was the only that really works for me, THANKS!!!
by the way, why does Chrome dev tools doesnt't show none of the linux browsers in options? evil guys

Comment: @Rodrigo Actually Spoofing user agent allows developers to check how their web apps will react to different browsers on different platforms. IMO Linux have very less market share (about 2% if we consider normal users) that's it doesn't have that. You can also observe that for mobile, we have UA built in for Android and iPhone only (no Windows, Symbian phones) because of their market share.

Comment: Awesome, this works - thanks! However, any refresh or restart breaks it again for me. I have to clear site data and re-connect after any refresh / restart :-/

Comment: I tried the first method (again) today and found that "chrome windows" is still a useragent that triggers the "please upgrade" message. I then selected "edge windows" and now I'm "in"....

Answer (score 13):

Installing a browser extension IMHO is a bit overkill.
Instead, I've changed the Chromium icon in gnome to run the browser with `--user-agent` option.

- Close Chromium.
- Customize .desktop:

  ```bsh
    cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
    vim ~/.local/share/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop
    # search "/snap/bin/chromium %U",
    # replace with "/snap/bin/chromium --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' %U"
  ```
- Then, reload Gnome:

  - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
  - Enter `restart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is awesome. Worked like magic, though I added a comment to help me out well into the future when I totally forgot I did this and can't figure out why the UA is hardcoded in the stupid shortcut. After doing this, you'll [obviously] have to drop and re-add your icon. If/when searching for the Chromium shortcut, you'll likely now [obviously] see more than one (probably two), and will have to figure out which one was just added. FYI, this even gets you past one more hurdle in getting Netflix to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Way better than accepted solution!

Comment: Is this still working for you? I tried and I still get the message asking me to update chrome

Comment: @maxime1992, i've reloaded the `web.whatsapp.com` tab on my `Chromium 80.0.3987.162 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)` and it works as usual.

Comment: @maxime1992, you can check which command line parameters are in use. Write `chrome://version/` in chromium address bar. It will show the browser version, but also the "Command Line:" section. My browser has `/snap/chromium/1071/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --password-store=basic --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --disable-webrtc-apm-in-audio-service`.

Comment: It's even easier when you create a Chromium shortcut via menu -> 'More tools' -> 'Create shortcut...' (and don't forget to click 'Open as window' to have it behave more like a real app). This will generate a .desktop file on your desktop, which you can edit with any text editor. There you can easily add the user-agent string as described above. When done, save the file and right click it. From the menu, select 'Allow Launching'. Done!

Answer (score 9):

This trick worked for me. I use Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Open url chrome://flags/#freeze-user-agent

Enable "Freeze User-Agent request header" option

once you relaunch browser, WhatsApp Web will open without problem.

Comment: Works perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: "Freeze User-Agent request header" has been re-named "Reduce User-Agent request header". However, enabling it appears to make no difference to this problem (Ubuntu 20.04).